# jquery ajax posting problems getting null value in alert

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, jquery

I'm using xml service to get response but i get null response from service.please help me solve this problem.............

By this service i am sending username and password but both wrong and right is going to succeess part because my service will return nulll value but it will be work fine in POSTMAN.........

```
      <script>
        function callXMLConnection() {
        alert("call Xml method call");  
        var un=$("#user").val();    
        var pw=$("#pwd").val();

        var myurl="http://192.162.1.153/EServices/retrieve.aspx";

        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({            
       data :"",
        type: "POST",
        url:myurl,
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain:true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
           alert("text : "+data);

                  },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("No data found."+jqXHR);  
            }
        });
    }

          $(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {
             $("#userInfo").click(function () { 
               callXMLConnection();

          });
        });
        </script>
```

this is my get authentication method

```
     Private Sub GenerateXMLPostMethod(ByVal Format As String, ByRef iostream As Stream)
       Try
          Dim WSCOMMAND As String, TMPSTR As String As String
          WS_USERID = Page.Request.Item("username")
          WSCOMMAND = Page.Request.Item("command")
          Select Case WSCOMMAND
             Case "get_authentication"
                 Application_Error("Responded at:" & System.DateTime.Now)

                    WSCOMMAND = Page.Request.Item("username")         
                    TMPSTR = Page.Request.Item("password")
                     DeviceID = Page.Request.Item("deviceid")
                     TMPSTR = Page.Request.Item("command")&"&username"&Page.Request.Item("username") & "&password"&Page.Request.Item("username")
                TMPSTR = Page.Request.Item("password")            'Passowrd



                LBFN_GET_USER(WSCOMMAND, TMPSTR, iostream)

            End Select
              Catch ex As Exception
                Application_Error("GenerateXMLPostMethod :" + ex.Message)
            End Try
```

Comment: your sending `data` is blank ?

Comment: this is my service url
http://localhost/EServices/retrieve.aspx?command=get_authentication&username=980&password=PMS@123
but i enable to send data in ajax i know i have to send
""command=get_authentication&username=980&password=PMS@123""
this data to ajax but i enable to send it in xml format

Answer (score 0):

In code there is no data(username, password ) pass to the server, modify the your code, with

```
data:""  // sending null value
```

use like this

```
data:{usename:un,password:pw}
```

In server page you can get the values from username,password using post method